# Is there a way to debug Serverless Framework Typescript functions deployed to AWS Lambda, without using serverless-offline?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

What is the best way to debug Typescript Serverless framework functions deployed to AWS Lambda without using `serverless-offline` package?

My project is quite reliant on other AWS services such as AWS Cognito, SNS, SQS etc, and other external services that debugging live deployed Lambda code looks like the best option, if possible.

I am starting to question Typescript as best choice for Lambda as its transpiles to optimized ES5 Javascript which is not suitable for live editing via AWS Lambda online editor.

What to use in complex AWS environments?

1. `serverless-offline`
2. do not use Typescript, use ES6, it can run on AWS Lambda Node.js environment
3. ?

Answer (score 0):

I am gathering information to setup a stack for a serverless architecture. I came across https://serverless-stack.com/, debug is said to be one of it main features, you might wanna try it. I will do in next months.